# How do you cross join multiple tables that only have one column in them, i am using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you cross join multiple tables that only have one column in them, i am using oracle?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are you sure you mean *cross* join? That will produce a result set with every combination between the two tables. If so it's just `select a.*, b.* from table1 a cross join table2 b`

Comment: `Select tbl1.col1, tbl2.col1 FROM tbl1 CROSS JOIN tbl2`

Comment: Yes I know , I want every possibility between all four tables. Each table only has one column

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2......................But then how do i cross join two more tables all in one statement?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go to the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and please refer the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join`s chain together:

```
select *
from a cross join b cross join c cross join d;
```